# Responsive Gallery acting weird

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an image gallery that will be fully responsive and attractive. But that is very hard when the images won't align like a normal set of images on a gallery, the images look great when you size down the window/gallery. But with the window full screen, the images start appearing weird and not in the order they should be.
If anyone knows what exactly went wrong or what to add please let me know.
Thanks!

```css
div.img {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.img:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
    padding: 0 6px;
    float: left;
    width: 24.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .responsive {
        width: 49.99999%;
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .responsive {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}


body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}

.navigation {
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
 position: relative;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.brand-text {
  font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: black;
 -webkit-transition: color 1000ms ease;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}


.brand-text:hover {
 color: grey;
 
}

.nav-brand {
 text-decoration:none;
}

.nav-menu {
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-link {
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 color: grey;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 -webkit-transition: color 700ms ease;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

.nav-link:hover {
 color: black;
}

.current {
  color: black;
}

.current:hover {
  color:
}

.about-section {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #f2f2f2;
  position: relative;
}

.me-image {
  width: 100%;
  
}

.about-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.about-title {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  
}

.about-me {
  font-family: 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif;
  line-height: 150%;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  clear: both;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Josh Corbett</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="description" content="Portfolio of Josh Corbett. Full of photography, art, graphics/illustrations, and maybe more!" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="images.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navigation">
  <a class="nav-brand" href="#"><h1 class="brand-text">Josh Corbett</h1></a>
  <div class="container">
   <nav class="nav-menu" role="navigation">
    <a class="nav-link current" href="Home.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="About.html">About</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="Blog.html">Blog</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
   
 <div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <img src="Photos/apple.png" alt="Apple Vector" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Apple Products Vector</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <img src="Photos/Panda.jpg" alt="Cute Panda" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Cute Panda</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <img src="Photos/2dlandscape.jpg" alt="Flat Landscape" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Flat Landscape</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <img src="Photos/jclogo.png" alt="JC Logo" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">JC Logo</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <img src="Photos/Leaf.JPG" alt="Leaf" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Raspberry Leaf</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <img src="Photos/Grass.JPG" alt="Grass" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Long Grass</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <img src="Photos/Me.jpg" alt="Me" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Just Me</div>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="footer">
     ©Josh Corbett 2016
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if your `.responsive` has `height` in `px` should solve thats because you have some long text like `Apple Products Vector` or minify `font-size`

Comment: The height adjusts the height of all of them, making them look really weird, but they did wrap correctly. But they did not turn out right.

Answer (score 1):

It's the longer text descriptions that when it wraps you see the "weirdness".

Adding white-space: nowrap; to .responsive will solve your problem.

I would suggest giving a technique like flexbox a try because you will be fighting with the browser a lot less. http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

Comment: whitespace: nowrap did absolutely nothing to .responsive. Flexbox didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an extra closing div tag, just 2 lines below the "Apple Products Vector" line, which could cause issues.

Second you need get your width and height hierarchy fixed. First you set the "img" width and height attributes, but then in the CSS you set the "div.img img" width and height, which, if I am not mistake, overwrites those values (it's best to set the image size in CSS only). Next the "responsive" div has its width set, and as it is a  percentage is not going to be 600px (img width) plus padding, margins, and borders, for all window sizes.

Third you need to learn a bit about float. Float was designed to allow text to wrap around an image or other block level element. And while it can be used to automatically shift block level elements (divs, img, ect) you have to think a bit differently. First keep in mind float has to know the size of every block level element if it is going to position things correctly this is why I mentioned your sizing issue prior to this. Next realize that float is trying to wrap each div around the other div's (if you think too hard about that your brain might explode). But div's aren't as flexible as a sentences and paragraphs. To simplify each div is first assigned its top position, and then assigned its left position. So for the first row, it will fill the first available slot from the left, but for the second row it with be filling from the top then left. So if one of those div is shorter than the others float will fill that space below it before it fills to the left.

Lastly you should put all the "responsive" div's in a wrapper div if you're going to use float, as float does check the parent elements style to help it make some decisions on positioning floated elements.

There is some good tutorials around on using float, in particular the pitfalls of using float, you may want to look them up as it will likely help you quite a bit.

Comment: That "extra" closing div tag closes the "img" div block. I also used float on almost everything, but then I took it off because it never worked. I also tried using flexbox, but that didn't work either.